# Node.js - "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "redis""

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, brunch

I'm trying to [build a simple "Twitter" style short messaging app](https://github.com/humphreybc/humphreybc.com) in Node.js which uses Redis as the database (although I've heard that MongoDB might be easier)...

I have found a few links that point me in the direction of https://github.com/mranney/node_redis so I set up a new Node.js project using **Brunch** and ran the following in my project directory as instructed:

```
npm install redis hiredis
```

I then added the following from the auth.js example to vendor/script.js

```
var redis  = require("redis"),
client = redis.createClient();
```

However when I run brunch w -s I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "redis"
```

I'm assuming that it's something to do with modules not being included into my project but I'm not really sure where to start. I added

```
"redis": "latest"
```

to my package.json file but that doesn't appear to do anything.

I also tried to install the redis module globally by running

```
sudo npm install -g redis
```

But still no luck.

I should also add that I have redis-server installed on OS X, and I can run it in the terminal:

```
$ redis-server
[2221] 17 Aug 10:48:42 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In     order to specify a config file use 'redis-server /path/to/redis.conf'
[2221] 17 Aug 10:48:42 * Server started, Redis version 2.4.13
[2221] 17 Aug 10:48:42 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
[2221] 17 Aug 10:48:42 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 922304 bytes in use
[2221] 17 Aug 10:48:47 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 922304 bytes in use
```

My application directory is a standard brunch install -

```
app
config.coffee
generators
node_modules
package.json
public
README.md
test
vendor
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What subdirectories and files are in the `node_modules` subdirectory of your project directory? Do they have the right permissions and owners?

Comment: @ebohlman http://i.imgur.com/0GqT0.png

Comment: That seems to all be in order. Can you `require()` any of the other modules in that directory?

Comment: @ebohlman Ah, no I can't. Get the same error when trying to require the other ones.

Comment: @ebohlman I have no idea why I can't require stuff in node_modules. Tried this on a blank install of brunch as well ("brunch new projectname") and I still get the error.

Comment: What does your whole project directory tree look like?

Comment: @ebohlman Easiest way to show you is probably for you to clone the repository. =)

https://github.com/humphreybc/humphreybc.com

Comment: Where in the directory hierarchy is node_modules located?

Comment: @ebohlman It's in the top level of the node.js / brunch install, so there's:

app
config.coffee
generators
node_modules
package.json
public
README.md
test
vendor

Comment: What does `console.log(process.cwd())` say if you put it at the top of your code?

Comment: @ebohlman "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined"

Comment: Try `process.cwd()` from the REPL. If that doesn't work, completely reinstall node since `process` is supposed to be a built-in global and your installation is badly hosed if it's not present.

Answer (score 1):

Brunch is html5 application assembler, not node.js, you can’t require node modules there.